# C# Stopwatch Class Imprecision

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have very simple Android app developed in VS. Basically i have 2 labels (textviews) and 1 button. Logic is when I press button Stopwatch starts and when next time button is pressed Stopwatch is stopped, calculation how much time has passed and Stopwatch restarted.

```
        Button takt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.takt);

        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

        TextView vv = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
        TextView aavv = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView2);

        long bpm = 0;

        takt.Click += delegate {
            if(st.ElapsedMilliseconds != 0) // so avoiding division by zero
            {
                bpm = 60000 / st.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                vv.Text = st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms";
                aavv.Text = bpm + " BPM";

            }

            st.Restart();

        };
```

So when I start to press button a little bit faster Stopwatch starts to act weird. Sometimes it shows 250ms next time 280ms and then it jumps to like 500ms but tapping is approximately constant(with variations 250-270ms). Question is why those jumps occurs and is there a way to not have those jumps?

EDIT:

```
        Button takt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.takt);
        TextView avgBPM = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);    
        TextView BPM = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView2);
        Button reset = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

        long bpm = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        long divide = 0;
        double avg = 0.0;

        avgBPM.Text = "Avg BMP: " + avg;
        BPM.Text = bpm + " BPM";

        takt.Click += delegate
        {
            st.Stop();
            if (st.ElapsedMilliseconds != 0)
            {
                divide++;
                bpm = 60000 / st.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                sum += bpm;
                avg = sum / divide;
                avgBPM.Text = "Avg BMP: " + avg;
                BPM.Text = bpm + " BPM";

            }

            st.Reset();
            st.Start();

        };
        reset.Click += delegate
        {
            bpm = 0;
            sum = 0;
            divide = 0;
            avg = 0;
            st.Stop();
            st.Reset();

            avgBPM.Text = "Avg BMP: " + avg;
            BPM.Text = bpm + " BPM";


        };
```

I have changed stopwatch now it's stops before computations, do all stuff, then restart stopwatch. Added averageBPM text and now it shows precise for average. Now I need help how to change UI in another thread. I tried creating new function **void change()** but I can't see textviews in that function.

Comment: "approximately constant" is not very accurate. You need to remember that 500 ms is ***half second***. Variation of 250 ms seems very reasonable for manual clicking.

Comment: It may not be the case but you are not if the previous delegate has completed execution you can find yourself in a position that you restart the stopwatch after calculating the bpm and before updating the text. Also the `elapsed` value and the value used for bpm calculation would be different if the calculation lasts more than 1 ms

Comment: @Guy Well if you start tapping with certain tempo you cant miss by that much. Four times tapping is between 250-270 and fifth time randomly jumps at 500+ms.

Comment: You are testing on a physical device and not an emulator right?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes yes, I know emulator is too slow for that kind of test.

Comment: I have tried your code, it works fine with me. when I click the button fast it shows 180ms around. BTW I have test it in the google emulator.

Comment: @MikeMa Is it possible for you to test it on physical device? I can provide link for apk.

Comment: Works fine in my nexus 5x android 7.1.1

Comment: @MikeMa Thank you I have tested it on Sony M2 Aqua with 4.4.4 and there I got those spikes. Anyway thank you for commenting. :)

Comment: you are not on a realtime OS and your program is not the only one running. The processor assigns time to your application and it is not guaranteed that your click gets processed immediately when you tap the screen. The faster the device the more likely you don't notice. The slower the device (or more pressure by parallel programs) the more often you see effects. -And: UI changes get changed only on one thread. If your UI updates something then everything else that wants to update the UI as well gets blocked.

Comment: @Uwe Yes that seems logicly. Do you have some suggestion how to improve counting and precision?

Comment: Minimum I would try to separate code that changes UI (vv.Text setter and aavv.Text setter) from any computations. Maybe cache the clicktimes in a table and update UI only from time to time or look at them after test ends. Maybe you can post the results if it changed anything?

Comment: @Uwe I need to update that after every click (or maybe on another thread - which was unsuccessful attempt) because I need to show BPM and ms between every tap. I have optimized the code so the counting is no longer active while computing all the stuff and also I have added avgBPM text so it computes the average BPM rate and its precise like very precise. **Code in edit**